# Handling deprecated Methods

Tags: java, android, deprecated

Usually when it comes to use deprecated methods, we uses something like this

```
public static void SetBackground(View view, Drawable icon) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
        Helper.SetBackground(view, icon);
    else view.setBackgroundDrawable(icon);
}

public class Helper {
    public static void SetBackground(View view, Drawable icon) {
        view.setBackground(icon);
    }
}
```

Now, its just an example. My question is, what if a deprecated method gets removed in future API then the app will end up showing VerifyError because it wont be able to find it, like here is `View.setBackgroundDrawable`. Maybe we need to use Helper2 class for it.

Answer (score 0):

One way is like you mention API levels. But better is to Use reflection and see if the method is supported by the android version or fail gracefully/use a newer method

```
 public static Method getResources;

    static {
            try {
                    Class<?> class[] = new Class[1];
                    class[0] = String.class;
                    getResources= Context.class.getMethod("getResources", class);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "getResources is deprecated");
            }
    }
```

put the above in a class that extends the application class and then call it this way

```
MyClass extends Application { ...}

if(MyClass.getResources!= null){
           //Do stuff

  } else {

//Fail or do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly ugly trick for dealing with this kind of thing:

Make two classes that implement an interface :

```
public interface DrawableUtil {
    void setBackground(View v, Drawable d);
}

public class PreJellyBeanDrawableUtil {
    void setBackground(View v, Drawable d) {
        v.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    }
}
public class JellyBeanDrawableUtil {
    void setBackground(View v, Drawable d) {
        v.setBackground(d);
    }
}
```

Now you can use the usual idiom to construct the appropriate implementation:

```
DrawableUtil util;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
    util = new JellyBeanDrawableUtil();
else 
    util = new PreJellyBeanDrawableUtil();
util.setBackground(view, icon);
```

This won't suffer from the VerifyError problem, because it will never load the class with the deprecated method on newer platforms.

Comment: yes it will need another Helper class, which I was trying to avoid. pff some of methods were deprecated just for names.